# Transistors basic question, Voltage is confusing me

Tags: transistors

> you can't go sticking a voltage across the base-emitter terminals,
>   because an enormous current will flow if the base is more positive
>   than the emitter by more than about 0.6 to 0.8 volt.

Base being more positive, is it saying that base has more holes ? And what does it mean that base is 0.6 volt more positive ? It also says: Vb= Ve+Vbe, the concept of voltage is really bothering me here, is this equation saying the voltage needed across base for current to flow throught it is equal to voltage across emitter plus the voltage drop from base to emitter ? What does this even mean ? These are probably very dumb questions but I'm really frustrated because anything I have read for the past 10 hours won't explain it in a more basic way.

Comment: Have you learned Kirchoff's Voltage Law (KVL)?

Answer (score 9):

They're not dumb questions but the concept isn't too difficult to understand.

A few notes:

- The base emitter junction appears as a diode.
- In forward conduction at moderate currents about 0.7 V is dropped across the junction.
- The base current rises *exponentially* with the base-emitter voltage so we need to limit this applied voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuZh43.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Various NPN transistor arrangements.*

In (a) there is no current limiter on the base. We can turn the transistor on by applying about half a volt or more to it but slight variations in voltage will cause large variations in the current through R1. This makes it very difficult to control. If the base voltage rises too much the transistor will be destroyed.

In (b) we have added a current limiting resistor to the base. Now we can apply, for example, 5 V to NODE1 and with a 1k resistor be sure that a maximum of almost 5 mA will flow into the base.

In (c) we can apply a voltage to NODE1 and current will flow into the base turning on the transistor. Current will flow through R3 causing a voltage drop across it and the emitter voltage will rise to about 0.7 V below that of NODE1.

(a) and (b) are common emitter mode as their emitters are connected to a fixed voltage. (c) is a common collector arrangement and is also called an "emitter follower" as the emitter voltage follows the base voltage (with the 0.7 V drop).

To answer your questions:

> Base being more positive, is it saying that base has more holes?

No. And thinking of holes and electrons doesn't help much. Just think of voltages and currents.

> And what does it mean that base is 0.6 volt more positive?

Explained above.

> It also says: Vb = Ve+Vbe.

It's just saying that when you're calculating voltages at any point in the circuits above you can reckon that the base voltage will be 0.6 or 0.7 V above the emitter voltage (when current is flowing into the base).

[image]

*Figure 2. Horowitz and Hill, The Art of Electronics. "Transistor Man" looks at the current at the base, and adjust the current at the collector so as to be a multiple of the base current.*

The image of Figure 2 may help a little.

Comment: In (a) you mention that a voltage Vbe can "turn on" the transistor and in (c) it is a current "turning on" the device. This could confuse the questioner. More than that, the scheme as given in (b) plays no role for practical amplifier circuits. Why do you not show the classical voltage divider concept? More than that, the picture from Horowitz/Hill is "incomplete" (as stated by Horowitz/Hill at the end of chapt. 2.09). The corrected voltage-control model (based on transconductance) is given in chapt. 2.10.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @LvW. I generally try to pitch my answers to this sort of question a little higher than the OP's current understanding and to give some sort of intuitive feel to the topic. Despite my choice of username, transistor theory is not my strong point so I don't venture too far down that road. To a certain extent the transistor is both voltage and current controlled as there is a direct relationship between the two. Feel free to write a parallel answer explaining the same points in a different way. OP hasn't given any feedback yet anyway.

Comment: I was writing no "parallel answer" because two answers do already exist explaining that and why the BJT is a voltage-controlled current source. No - it is not "both voltage and current controilled". Without any doubt, there is a base current - but without any control function. It simply does exist and - according to the famous Barrie Gilbert - it must be treated as a "defect".

Comment: "*Without any doubt, there is a base current - but without any control function.*" My first thought on that is, "Why do treat \$ H_{fe} \$ as being so significant then?" We use it to calculate the current gain in an unsaturated transistor and push in some extra current to ensure saturation when required.

Answer (score 2):

This can simply be reduced to your usual voltage/circuit analysis problem. There's no need to think about electrons/holes.

Rearranging the equation Vb = Ve + Vbe would be Vbe = Vb - Ve, which is your typical voltage equation and applies to almost anything, not just the base-emitter voltage of a transistor.

This equation tells you that the voltage difference between the base and emitter must equal the voltage at the base (in reference to ground) minus the voltage at the emitter (in reference to ground) Typically, Vbe in a BJT is a fixed voltage around 0.6V - 0.8V when operating in the forward active region (which is the usual assumption when first learning about BJT transistors)

For example, let's say that your emitter is directly connected to ground (Ve = 0V). Assuming the transistor is operating in the forward-active region, Vbe = 0.6V. Plugging into the voltage equation you have gives you Vb = 0.6

Answer (score 1):

> you can't go sticking a voltage across the base-emitter terminals, because an enormous current will flow if the base is more positive than the emitter by more than about 0.6 to 0.8 volt.

The relation between \$I_C\$ and \$V_{BE}\$ is known as the Ebers-Moll equation, and is given \$I_C=I_S .e^{\frac{V_{BE}}{V_T}}.\$ In this equation \$I_S\$ is the saturation current of the particular transistor (e.g. for 2N3904 it's \$ \approx10^{-14}\$). \$V_{BE}\$ is the voltage across the base-emitter junction. For silicon BJTs this value is between \$0.6\$ to \$0.8\$ Volts but for germanium transistors it can be as low as \$0.3V\$. \$V_T\$ is given by \$\frac{k(T+273^{\circ}C)}{q}\$, where \$k\$ is the Boltzman's constant and q the electron charge. T is the temperature and is give in unit of Celsius. At room temperature it's about \$25mV\$ but it increases as temperature goes up.

According to the Ebers-Moll equation, \$V_{BE}\$ can be written \$ V_{BE}=V_T. \ln \frac{I_C}{I_S}\$. In this equation \$V_T\$ has a positive tempco but the stronger temperature dependence of \$I_S(T)\$, which appears in the denominator of the logarithmic term, almost dominates and causes an overall \$- \frac{2.1mV}{\ ^oC}\$ change in \$V_{BE}\$ (for a fixed collector current). This suggests that the base-emitter voltage \$V_{BE}\$ increases \$60mV\$ per decade of collector current, or the collector current doubles for each \$18mV\$ change in \$V_{BE}\$. The Ebers-Moll equation also suggests that at \$V_{BE}\$ fixed the collector current doubles for an \$8 ^oC\$ rise.

So a small change in \$V_{BE}\$ causes an enormous change in the collector current. This is why it says you can't stick a voltage across the base-emitter junction and be happy with that.